# Mockito mock class called inside test class

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I'm using Java to code a project in spring boot with Mockito. I'm new to Mockito, and I'm having trouble understanding how to mock inner classes that are causing the test class to fail. The methods for the inner classes are very complex, and I just need them to return an object of type ReturnData, whose value I choose. Example code is shown below:

```
public class class1() {

    public void methodToBeTested() {
        ...
        ReturnData rd = class2.method(...); //Not getter or setter, a method that has its own functionality
        ...
    }
    public void testClass1Method() {
        class2 c = mock(class2.class);
        class1ReturnType t = class1.methodToBeTested(c);
        //Confused on what follows, need class2 method to return what I want it to return. I need to mock it, I have no other choice, but don't know how to access it

    }
}
```

I have been scouring Stack Overflow, but can't find anything that answers my question, and I don't know if this is even possible. I need to somehow access class2 and have its method return different ReturnData values depending on what I'm testing for in the unit test. There are multiple classes called in the class1 method, but I'm only showing one for clarity.

Comment: Can you maybe get a little bit more into detail on your example code? Your `methodToBeTested` doesn't have a parameter, while the call to it does pass on that parameter. Also why is your `testClass1Method()` contained in the class to be tested? Thats weird.

Comment: Also: do you want to mock a static method? Your call to `class2.method(...)` could be a call to a static method, but as you are obviously not adhere to java naming conventions as class names starting with uppercase letters, while parameter or variable names start with lowercase letters, I have to ask this additional question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

When thenReturn will solve this problem, but only if there are no bugs in the internal classes, which does not apply to my situation unfortunately